# How to setup and configure HA Journal Server (High Availability) for Blazegraph

Tags: java, blazegraph

The blazegraph documentation for High Availability lacks. For starters, the documentation states to download the source code and run `"ant deploy-artifact"`. This is incorrect as they've transitioned to maven and you should really run `"ant maven-deploy"` (exec's mvn clean deploy under the hood).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to successfully execute the "deploy" argument.

Has anyone had any luck setting up the `HAJournalServer` for `Blazegraph`? Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

I've attempted to download the source code and run `"ant maven-deploy"` (as what's provided in the build.xml) but that fails on dependencies that don't exist anymore (`maven-installer-plugin`) for example.

Answer (score 3):

So I've contacted the authors of Blazegraph, turns out all HA features do NOT function, and development stopped on those features years ago.  Hopefully this answer helps others in the same boat as I!